# Json Parse for an Integer as the key in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have searched for almost 2hrs now but cannot find anyone using an integer as the key. My json object looks like:

```
{"342227492064425":
    {"added":"2020-10-04T23:02:28.030432",
     "listed":"2020-10-04T23:02:28.030432",
     "subscribed":"2020-10-04T23:02:28.030432"},
"342731155590705":
    {"added":"2020-10-04T23:02:28.030432",
     "listed":"2020-10-04T23:02:28.030432",
     "subscribed":"2020-10-04T23:02:28.030432"}
}
```

How do I parse this?? I tried using data.map and using a for loop (data.length) but all in vain. Please help.

My attempt:

```
fetch(url).then((response)=>{
        return response.json();
    }).then((data)=>{
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        subscription += data[i].subscribed
        //data.length doesn't work
    }
}
```

Edit: I want to use it in my HTML code. Also I do not know how many numbers will come in the json file so I want to output a map which I can use like: data[0].susbcribed. Here I want to know how much length it will take for the var i.

Comment: The term *parse* refers to what `response.json()` does. You can use `Object.keys()` to get an array of property names from your object, as one possibility. It's not at all clear what you want to do however.

Comment: `data.map()` doesn't work, because `data.map` is not a function. What do you need to do with your object? I agree with @Pointy, it is not clear what you want to do

Comment: `data.map()` doesn't work because `data` is an object which doesn't have the `map()` method. It would need to be an array in order to have `map()`. Same for `data.length`. When something is enclosed in curly braces `{}` it's an object. When it's enclosed in square brackets `[]` it's an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing special about keys that look like integers. In JavaScript, property names are always strings, and the fact that they look like large integers is irrelevant. Just treat it like any other object.

You can use `Object.keys()` to get an array of property names, `Object.values()` to get an array of property values, and `Object.entries()` to get a 2-dimensional array of names and values.

```
Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(`${key} added on ${value.added}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `data.length` in **Objects** either should be used for count characters in string and/or array length

> A Number, representing the number of elements in the array object

Reference: [JavaScript Array length Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_array.asp)

I have a suggestion for you if you need to use `data.length` so basically push your objects to a new array.

There is many ways to do this e.g.

```
    var data = [];
var objects = {"342227492064425":
    {"added":"2020-10-04T23:02:28.030432",
     "listed":"2020-10-04T23:02:28.030432",
     "subscribed":"2020-10-04T23:02:28.030432"},
"342731155590705":
    {"added":"2020-10-04T23:02:28.030432",
     "listed":"2020-10-04T23:02:28.030432",
     "subscribed":"2020-10-04T23:02:28.030432"}
}
// Convert Objects to Array via forEach function and Push method
Object.entries(objects).forEach((key, value) => data.push(key));
```

Array Values:

```
console.log(data);
```

Output:

```
/*

["342227492064425", {added: "2020-10-04T23:02:28.030432", listed: "2020-10-04T23:02:28.030432", subscribed: "2020-10-04T23:02:28.030432"}],
["342731155590705", {added: "2020-10-04T23:02:28.030432", listed: "2020-10-04T23:02:28.030432", subscribed: "2020-10-04T23:02:28.030432"}]

*/
```

First ID Value

```
console.log(data[0][0])
```

Second ID Value

```
console.log(data[1][0])
```

Access First Object Values

```
console.log(data[0][1].added)
console.log(data[0][1].listed)
console.log(data[0][1].subscribed)
```

Access Second Object Values

```
console.log(data[1][1].added)
console.log(data[1][1].listed)
console.log(data[1][1].subscribed)
```

Now, you can use `data.length` output is: `(2)`

**[Live Example: Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/s1bp/pen/ExyVpbq)**